# how to resolve the warning in R

Tags: r, missing-data

The data i am using looks as shown below, it has 50000 instances and 32 variables....
The missing values are present in many varibles ,..
sorry was unable to post the entire data..

I used

```
    library(zoo)
    d$V5 <- na.locf(d$V5)
```

and i further checked for Gini value and it gave me the output as below

```
Gini(d$V5)
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In sum(x * 1:n) : Integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
2: In n * sum(x) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

But d$V5 corresponds to age which is a number
The aim was to find Gini and information gain and to plot a decision tree, due to missing values the decision tree split is one.
Hence, filling missing values was necessary.
Data:

```
1   022 F   O   044 0       N   31  12  00P         0012    Y   Y   N   Y   0048    731 0.000000    Y   N   0   VERA    LUCIA   N   N   300.000000  0000    00  N   0
2   015 F   S   018 0       Y   31  20  00  P   0216    Y   Y   Y   Y   0012    853 0.000000    Y   N   0   SARA    FELIPE  N   N   300.000000  0000    00  N   0
3   024 F   C   022 0       Y   31  08  00  P   0048    Y   N   Y   Y   0012    040 0.000000    Y   N   0   HELENA  DOMINGOS SOGRA  N   N   229.000000  0000    00  N   0
4   012 F   C   047 0       N   31  25  00  P   0180    Y   Y   N   Y   0024    035 0.000000    Y   N   0   JACI    VALERIA ALEXANDRA TRAJANO   N   N   304.000000  0000    00  N   0
5   016 F   S   028 0       Y   31  25  00  O   0012    Y   Y   Y   Y   0012    024 0.000000    Y   N   0   MARCIA CRISTINA ZANELLA SANDRO L P MARTINS  N   N   250.000000  0000    00  N   0

.....

49998   023 F   S   023 0       Y   31  28  00  P   0264    Y   Y   Y   Y   0012    991 0.000000    Y   N   0   NOVINA  GLAUCIA N   N   240.000000  0000    00  N   1
49999   009 F   C   038 0       Y   5   28  00  P   0048    Y   Y   Y   Y   0204    040 0.000000    Y   N   0   LILIANE FIGUEIREDO  MIRNA CARVALHO NASCIMENTO   N   N   616.000000  0000    00  N   0
50000   022 M   S   029 0       Y   31  23  00  P   0048    Y   Y   N   Y   0036    026 0.000000    Y   N   0   TITO MARTINS        N   N   341.000000  0000    00  N   0
```

Comment: This isn't how this site works. We don't do work requests or demands. You need to put some effort into a real question: try something specific, show us your code, give us a reproducible example.

Comment: please see the code i tried. I am sorry was struck while working hence requested..

Comment: "[This code] didn't work" isn't helpful. What was the output of the code you tried, and what did you expect it to be?

Comment: Sorry was unsure how to post. I re edited the question. If you require more information please let me.

Comment: Is it as simple as needing to assign the output? `d$V5 <- na.locf(d$V5)`?

Comment: I did that, yet it displays the same error.
I am not sure what is the mistake

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning; and it tells you what to do (convert the column to numeric).

Comment: Column 5 is already a number, it represents the age.

Comment: @PavithraCReddy, `numeric` is different from `integer`. See the answer below.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand. The post below gave me the result expected.
New to coding, did nt know the difference. will learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting has nothing to do with missing values (which may or may not present a problem of their own). It can easily be reproduced by doing:

```
sum(1:100000)
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In sum(1:1e+05) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
```

And can also be avoided by converting to doubles:

```
sum(as.numeric(1:100000))
#[1] 5000050000
```

So do

```
d$V5 = as.numeric(d$V5)
```

and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks eddi, it's perfect.
Do you know how to find the Information gain using r?
could you tell me know if you have any idea about it.

Comment: I don't know how "Information gain" is defined ...? I don't really know much about the topic of your interest, you might want to post a separate question about that (and I'd include either a definition or a reference to the definition of that quantity).

Comment: Thanks eddi.
I wrote a question on it, I am yet to get any response.
Google says use FSelector package.
when i try to use it, a message is displayed saying
        Error in library(FSelector) : there is no package called 'FSelector'

I do not know how alternative packages work.

Comment: did you install it first? `install.packages('FSelector')`

Comment: I downloaded it online and ran few files. Sorry, Did nt know about install.packages('..'). Installing now. Thanks a lot Eddi.
but there is again a message 
        

        package 'FSelector' is available as a source package but not as a binary

        Warning message:
         package 'FSelector' is not available

Comment: Its ok will try for alternative, anyway thanks a lot..